# Swagger/Swashbuckle do not recognize JObject in request model

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, swashbuckle, webapi

My Environment: Asp.NET WebAPI、NET Framework 4.5.2、Swashbuckle.Core 5.6.0

For some reason, My controller must Inherit the previous same Controller, like this

```
public class User100Controller : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public virtual string Get()
    {
        return "1.0.0";
    }
}

public class User101Controller : User100Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public override string Get()
    {
        return "1.0.1";
    }
}
```

Run directly, and swagger ui page show correctly

[sample picture, pls right click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rAA49.png)

But if I add a Post Action with params, swagger ui do not recongnize Request Model

**UserModel** and **UserModelSex**

```
/// <summary>
/// UserModel
/// </summary>
public class UserModel
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Name
    /// </summary>
    public string name { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    /// <summary>
    /// Age
    /// </summary>
    public int age { get; set; } = 0;
}

/// <summary>
/// UserModelSex
/// </summary>
public class UserModelSex : UserModel
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Sex
    /// </summary>
    public int sex { get; set; } = -1;
}
```

**User100Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
[SwaggerResponse(200, "success", typeof(UserModel))]
public virtual IHttpActionResult SaveUser([FromBody] UserModel model)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.name) || model.age == 0)
    {
        return Ok("error");
    }

    //...
    return Ok("success");
}
```

[sample picture, pls right click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/03R4O.png)

This is correct effect, Now if I override this **SaveUser** Action in User101ontroller, and pass the new request model **UserModelSex**, I got an error, Because of Override Method must have the same param List with the parent Method, So I change it like this

```
public class User100Controller : ApiController
{
    [HttpPost]
    [SwaggerResponse(200, "success", typeof(UserModel))]
    public virtual IHttpActionResult SaveUser([FromBody] JObject json)
    {
        var model = json.ToObject<UserModel>();
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.name) || model.age == 0)
        {
            return Ok("error");
        }

        //...
        return Ok("success");
    }
}

public class User101Controller : User100Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    [SwaggerResponse(200, "success", typeof(UserModelSex))]
    public override IHttpActionResult SaveUser([FromBody] JObject json)
    {
        var model = json.ToObject<UserModelSex>();
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.name) || model.age == 0 || model.sex == -1)
        {
            return Ok("error");
        }

        //...
        return Ok("success");
    }
}
```

swagger ui do not recongnize JObject

[sample picture, pls right click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Iph6.png)

how to show **UserModel** and **UserModeSex** in request model, like pic 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I solve it by myself

- add SwaggerRequestModelAttribute.cs

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class SwaggerRequestModelAttribute : Attribute
{
    public Type RequestModel { get; private set; }

    public string ModelName { get; private set; }

    public SwaggerRequestModelAttribute(Type requestModel)
    {
        RequestModel = requestModel;
        ModelName = requestModel.Name;
    }
}
```

- then, Mark [SwaggerRequestModel] to the Controllers

```
[HttpPost]
[SwaggerRequestModel(typeof(UserModel))]
public virtual IHttpActionResult SaveUser([FromBody] JObject json)
{
    var model = json.ToObject<UserModel>();
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.name) || model.age == 0)
    {
        return Ok("error");
    }

    //...
    return Ok("success");
}
```

- Add ModelInBodyOperationFilter.cs

```
public class ModelInBodyOperationFilter : IOperationFilter
{
    public void Apply(Operation operation, SchemaRegistry schemaRegistry, ApiDescription apiDescription)
    {
        if (operation.parameters == null) operation.parameters = new List<Parameter>();

        var attribute = apiDescription.GetControllerAndActionAttributes<SwaggerRequestModelAttribute>();
        if (attribute.Any())
        {
            if (operation.parameters.Count > 0 && operation.parameters[0].schema.type == "object")
            {
                if (!schemaRegistry.Definitions.ContainsKey(attribute.First().ModelName))
                    schemaRegistry.GetOrRegister(attribute.First().RequestModel);

                operation.parameters.RemoveAt(0);
                operation.parameters.Add(new Parameter
                {
                    name = "-",
                    @in = "body",
                    required = true,
                    schema = new Schema { @ref = $"#/definitions/{attribute.First().RequestModel.Namespace}.{attribute.First().ModelName}" }
                });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

- also, in SwaggerConfig.Register()

```
c.UseFullTypeNameInSchemaIds();
c.OperationFilter<ModelInBodyOperationFilter>();
```

- at last, run the app and preview it

[sample picture, pls right click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zPeFW.png)